# Accessing NSMutableArray from inside for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am very new at iOS and objective-c development, so I am struggling with an understanding of how I do this.

First my code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)messagesGetList
{  

NSMutableArray *messageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxx/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {    
                                         for (NSDictionary * dataDict in JSON) {

                                             [messageList addObject: dataDict];

                                         }                                             
                                     } 
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error);        

                                     }];

[operation start];


return messageList;
}
```

What I am having a problem with, is that I can not access the NSMutableArray *messageList inside my for (NSDictionary * dataDict in JSON) loop.
I.e. nothing is added to the array while executing my loop.

How do I access the array from within my loop?

Thanks in advance for your help,
fischer

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"loop");` right above your `addObject` line. Make sure you are actually in the loop at all.

Comment: Probably want to log the JSON object (or just set a breakpoint and inspect in a debugger) to make sure you are getting back an array.

Comment: It's in the loop two times.. And loggin JSON returns a nicely formatted array! Thanks for your suggestions, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `+JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:` takes blocks to be called on success and on failure, it's a good guess that this method runs asynchronously. So, if you're checking the array that's returned from your `-messagesGetList` right away, it's likely to be empty. If you wait a while before checking, you may see it fill up.

Comment: I had not thought about this at all.. That's a very good point. I will check if that's the case :)

Comment: @fischer: Specifically, I think you want to do `[operation waitUntilFinished]`. But note that this will lock your app up until the operation is finished (barring running your own run loop). You'd *probably* be better off not trying to force this to be synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add the `__block` storage modifier to your `NSMutableArray` variable, in order for it to be mutable inside the block response.

```
__block NSMutableArray *messageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I tried adding the __block modifier. I made no difference, sadly. I am guessing the problem might be what Caleb suggested instead.. I had not thought about that at all! But thanks anyway! Great help :)

Comment: Thinking it through a little more, the code isn't going to modify `messageList`, it's going to modify the mutable array to which `messageList` refers. So `__block` probably isn't helpful here.

Comment: No, this doesn't matter. The `__block` qualifier is only necessary if you are modifying the _pointer_ (i.e., re-assigning a new object). You can send messages to a mutable object inside a block all day long without problems. /cc @Caleb

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a delegate object to this method, and send a message to the delegate when the network request has completed. This is a best practice on the iOS platform.